# is there anyway to make the code more simple & efficient?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, loops

this is my code in `index.blade.php`

1. HTML

```
@foreach($sesis as $sesi)
<td>{{ $sesi->waktu }}
     <label class="switch switch-text switch-info switch-pill" id="label-switch{{ $sesi->id }}">
         <input type="checkbox" id="switch-sesi{{ $sesi->id }}" name="status" value="{{ $sesi->id }}" class="switch-input">
         <span data-on="Ada!" data-off="Absen" class="switch-label"></span>
         <span class="switch-handle"></span>
     </label>
</td>
@endforeach
```

2. jquery

```
@foreach($sesis as $sesi)
    $('#switch-sesi{{ $sesi->id }}').on('change', function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
            console.log($(this).val());
        }else{
            console.log('tidak checked');
        }
    });
@endforeach
```

there is no problem with my code, but it looks like my code not efficient (see my jquery code). I'm trying to get id attributes from the input type checkbox with looping all the block code. I'm just wondering, is there anyway to efficient it ?

Comment: there is no need you attach the event doing a loop over all, just in you frist loop you can add to your <input ... /> the onchange event adding a callback

Comment: I'm just wonderung what you need all these IDs for?

Comment: I'd recommend the Stack Exchange for Code Review for future posts :) https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create the jquery for every element, you can use something like the `id^=switch-sesi` to select all elements who's `id` is starting with `sesi`

```
$('*[id^=switch-sesi]').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    console.log($(this).val());
  } else {
    console.log('tidak checked');
  }
});
```

**Working demo**

```js
$('*[id^=switch-sesi]').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    console.log($(this).val());
  } else {
    console.log('tidak checked');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td>
  <label class="switch switch-text switch-info switch-pill" id="label-switch1">
         <input type="checkbox" id="switch-sesi1" name="status" value="1" class="switch-input">
         <span data-on="Ada!" data-off="Absen" class="switch-label"></span>
         <span class="switch-handle"></span>
     </label>
</td>
<td>
  <label class="switch switch-text switch-info switch-pill" id="label-switch2">
         <input type="checkbox" id="switch-sesi2" name="status" value="2" class="switch-input">
         <span data-on="Ada!" data-off="Absen" class="switch-label"></span>
         <span class="switch-handle"></span>
     </label>
</td>
```

Comment: thank you for the response, sir. it works! I didn't about that before...

Comment: @FajarAlamRahmatSidik No problem, happy to help,

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".switch-input").on("change",function(){
  if($(this).is(":checked")){
    alert($(this).val());
  }else{
    alert("Unchecked.");
  }
});
```

```css
input{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" class="switch-input" value="A">

<input type="checkbox" class="switch-input" value="B">

<input type="checkbox" class="switch-input" value="C">

<input type="checkbox" class="switch-input" value="D">

<input type="checkbox" class="switch-input" value="E">
```

Since you already have the class switch-input in your input field (checkbox), you could just use that reference in your jquery instead of looping through them to add the event handler.

Instead of foreach, just have one;

```
$('.switch-input').on('change', function(){
  if($(this).is(":checked")){
    console.log($(this).val());
  }else{
     console.log('tidak checked');
  }
});
```